# Using class as key in NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, dictionary

I'm writing a contextual "factory" that will maintain a dictionary of converter/acting objects which inherit from some Converter class. This class has a method:

```
- (Class)classResponsibility
```

Or something similar, such that a StringConverter class would implement the method as:

```
- (Class)classResponsibility {
    return [NSString class];
}
```

Then to store that converter in the dictionary, I had hoped on doing something like:

```
[converters setValue:stringConverter forKey:[stringConverter classResponsibility]];
```

But the compiler complains that the type "Class" is an invalid parameter type for argument 2 of the setValue:forKey: method. I had wanted to avoid setting the key as the Class's name ("NSString"), but if that's the best solution than I'll go with it.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You're using `setValue:forKey:` which only takes `NSString`s as keys. you should be using `setObject:forKey:` instead. A class object (pointers to class objects can be passed as type `Class`) is a full-fledged Objective-C object (a class object is an instance of its meta-class, and you can use all the `NSObject` methods on a class object; read more about meta-classes [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/what-is-meta-class-in-objective-c.html)), so they can be used anywhere objects are used.

Another requirement for keys of a dictionary is that they support copying (i.e. have the `copyWithZone:` method. Do class objects support this method? In fact, it does. The NSObject class defines a *class method* `+copyWithZone:`, whose [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-copyWithZone_) explicitly says that it "lets you use a class object as a key to an NSDictionary object". I think that's the answer to your question.

Comment: as of XCode 4.5, you need to first cast it to not get a warning:[dictionary setObject:object forKey:(id <NSCopying>)someClass]; see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525324/unable-to-use-class-as-a-key-in-nsdictionary/12525479#12525479

Comment: Do you know the technical reason why keys must conform to `NSCopying`?

Comment: @Drux my guess is that NSDictionary does not want to retain objects that might be released by someone else when they are not needed. If NSDictionary retains the object, someone else releases it, then the object is only retained by NSDictionary instance as the key and when value for the key is removed - the object is removed as well. So copying makes the key object available only to the NSDictionary (if you look at `allKeys` method it also returns a copy of the keys array).

Comment: @Drux I suspect NSDictionary's implementation makes some optimizing assumptions about keys not being mutated once they are set.

Comment: Note that if autocomplete doesn't display `-setObject:forKey` as an option, you may have declared an (immutable) NSDictionary instead of an NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: @Drux Frank is partially right, if a key's hash changes it will break lookup. Keys must be immutable.

Answer (score 30):

Your other option is to use `[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:yourObjectHere]` to construct the key from something other than a string. I ran into a similar problem and I wanted to use a CoreData object as the key and something else as the value. This `NSValue` method worked perfect and I believe was it's original intent. To get back to the original value just call `nonretainedObjectValue`

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for that. I've unfortunately already gone down the other path, but in the future I will remember to give this a try.

Comment: Very awesome alternative rather than implementing copyWithZone in a million class for me :)

Answer (score 5):

While a Class object makes a perfectly good key in an NSDictionary, it's worth mentioning NSMapTable, which is modeled after NSDictionary, but provides more flexibility as to what kind of objects are suitable for use as keys and/or values, [documented](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSMapTable_class/Reference/NSMapTable.html) to support weak references and arbitrary pointers.

Comment: This should be the new preferred solution iOS 6 and beyond.

Comment: Can you use weak for class key with NSMapTable? Any possibility it will silently die?

Answer (score 4):

`-setValue:forKey:` is documented to take an `NSString` as the second parameter. You'll have to use `NSStringFromClass()` and `NSClassFromString()` as adaptors.

Comment: Don't the docs for setValue:forKey: say that the key only has to be an object when using key-value coding? Otherwise, couldn't it be any object that implements NSCopying protocol, like NSDictionary?

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for the **setObject:forKey**: method instead of setValue:forKey:. The method signature for setObject:forKey: accepts (id) as both parameter types, and is much better suited.

Comment: @Graham Lee: Classes do implement NSCopying. See the documentation of the +copyWithZone: method: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-copyWithZone_

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar situation crop up with the exact same error message:

```
[tempDictionary setObject:someDictionary forKey:someClass];
```

All I did was implement the `NSCopying` protocol in `someClass`:

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    id copy = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] init];
    [copy setId:[self id]];
    [copy setTitle:[self title]];
    return copy;
}
```

I think what was happening was that a copy of `someClass` was being made in order to be used as the key, but since my object didn't know how to copy itself (deriving from `NSObject` it didn't have a `copyWithZone` in the superclass) it balked.

One thing I've found with my approach is that it's use an object as a key. Unless I already have the object instantiated, I'm constantly calling `allKeys` or just otherwise enumerating over the dictionary.

[After writing this, I see that you want to store the class as such as the key. I'm leaving this out there because I would have saved a lot of time if I had found my answer when I was searching SO. I didn't find anything like this then.]

Comment: I just stumbled on this problem today, but had this other class working flawlessly for many months and didn't understand why. Anyone would know a reason ? "Model" is a custom class deriving from NSObject only (not NSCoding compliant) `static NSMutableDictionary *singletonInstances; 

@implementation SingletonModel


+(void)initialize {
 singletonInstances = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
}

+(void)setSharedModel:(Model*)aModel {
 if (![singletonInstances objectForKey:[aModel class]]) {
  [singletonInstances setObject:aModel forKey:[aModel class]];
 }
}`

Comment: @nobre: class objects can be used as keys. see http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-copyWithZone_

Comment: This post has a good discussion of the pitfalls of implementing `NSCopying`: http://robnapier.net/blog/implementing-nscopying-439

Answer (score 1):

You can use classes as `NSDictionary`'s keys like this:

```
@{
    (id)[MyClass1 class] : @1,
    (id)[MyClass2 class] : @2,
    (id)[MyClass3 class] : @3,
    (id)[MyClass4 class] : @4,
};
```

Or even like this:

```
@{
    MyClass1.self : @1,
    MyClass2.self : @2,
    MyClass3.self : @3,
    MyClass4.self : @4,
};
```