# Unable to use 'class' as a key in NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, class, nsdictionary

I'm trying to use a class as a key in an `NSDictionary`. I looked at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730076/using-class-as-key-in-nsdictionary) and what I have is pretty much the same; I'm using `setObject: forKey:`. However, XCode complains, saying `Incompatible pointer types sending 'Class' to parameter of type 'id<NSCopying>'`. The call I have is:

```
[_bugTypeToSerializerDictionary setObject: bugToStringSerializer 
                                forKey: [bugToStringSerializer serializedObjectType]];
```

`bugToStringSerializer` is an instance of `BugToStringSerializer` whose concrete implementations implement `serializedObjectType`. An example of a concrete implementation looks like this:

```
- (Class) serializedObjectType {
    return [InfectableBug class];
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You can only use objects as keys whose class (the Class object's *metaclass* in this case) conforms to NSCoding. Classes don't.

Comment: @H2CO3 interesting... how is it then, that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730076/using-class-as-key-in-nsdictionary) works?

Comment: I just tried it and it actually works, seemingly classes can be copied. I was wrong, sorry.

Comment: Hmm, which brings me back to my question :) What am I doing wrong? I don't see anything different in what I am doing, from the answer provided in that question. Very odd!

Comment: what you're doing wrong is that you're too sensitive to the compiler's false positives :) See my answer. (Seriously, you're not doing anything wrong.)

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks! Looks like the compiler is very picky!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

(It seems that classes *do conform* to `NSCopying`, however their type is not `id <NSCopying>`.) **Edit:** classes do not conform to protocols. Of course the essential is that classes respond to the `copy` and `copyWithZone:` messages (and that's why you can safely ignore the warning in this case). Their type is *still* not `id <NSCopying>`.)  That's why the compiler complains.

If you really don't want that ugly warning, just perform an explicit type conversion:

```
[dictionary setObject:object forKey:(id <NSCopying>)someClass];
```

Comment: Ah, ok. Yes, I should have made it clear in the question that this was a compiler warning and not an error! Thank you!

Comment: @VivinPaliath I know that's a warning - I often read compiler messages, so I'm used to what a warning and an error is :)

Comment: ...  @VivinPaliath  in ios6 my compiler treat it as error. - =|||

Comment: @(incomprehensible Unicode characters): that's the matter of compiler settings. If you remove `-Werr -Wall -pedantic` from the compiler options, it decays into a warning.

Comment: Now that **is really not supposed to throw an error.** What's the error message?

Comment: Class objects (instances of metaclasses) do not actually conform to any protocols except `NSObject` (which they inherit from the root class `NSObject`). However, they do respond to the `copyWithZone:` message, due to the `+copyWithZone:` method in `NSObject`, which is all that `NSDictionary` cares about.

Comment: @newacct The first part of your comment is right, I fixed it. However, it's not true that `Class` itself inherits from NSObject.

Comment: @H2CO3: Metaclasses follow the same inheritance chain as their classes. And at the end the metaclass of the root class inherits from the root class itself.

Comment: @newacct good find! However, I'm not sure in the second part. I just tried `NSStringFromClass([NSObject class])` and it's null, not NSObject.

Comment: @H2CO3: first of all `[NSObject class]` is just the NSObject class (the `+class` method simply returns the thing it was called on). To get `NSObject`'s metaclass, you need to use `object_getClass([NSObject class])`. You will find that `class_getSuperclass(object_getClass([NSObject class])) == [NSObject class]` is true

Comment: @newacct Yeah, typo, I meant `[[NSObject class] class]`. But nevertheless, I'll try that tomorrow :)

Comment: this answer should be [dictionary setObject:object forKey:(id <NSCopying>)someClass];  not NSCoding, using NSCoding does NOT make the warning go away...

Comment: @odyth Right, overseen it, sorry. Fixed.

Comment: This is documented: [+ copyWithZone:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/copyWithZone:) — “ This method exists so class objects can be used in situations where you need an object that conforms to the NSCopying protocol.”

Answer (score 19):

Aha,I just fixed the bug in my project.

use this:

```
NSStringFromClass([Someclass class]);
```

Comment: I don't see why this was down voted, it's a perfectly suitable example when paired with NSClassFromString();

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are certainly helpful, but in this case it probably makes more sense to just use an [NSMapTable](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSMapTable_class/Reference/NSMapTable.html), which does not copy the key unlike NSDictionary, and just retains it with a strong pointer (by default, although this can be changed).

Then you can just use your original code with no modifications.

```
NSMapTable *_bugTypeToSerializerDictionary = [NSMapTable new];
...
[_bugTypeToSerializerDictionary setObject: bugToStringSerializer
                                   forKey: [bugToStringSerializer serializedObjectType]];
```

It's less hacky, and is clearer at conveying programmer intent.

For extra style points you could give the instance variable a slightly more fitting name like`_bugTypeToSerializerMap`.

Answer (score 0):

This is my usual code:

```
@{
    (id)[MyClass1 class] : @1,
    (id)[MyClass2 class] : @2,
    (id)[MyClass3 class] : @3,
    (id)[MyClass4 class] : @4,
};
```

But recently I've discovered this approach:

```
@{
    MyClass1.self : @1,
    MyClass2.self : @2,
    MyClass3.self : @3,
    MyClass4.self : @4,
};
```