# Can I use NSPredicate as key in a NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, nspredicate, nscopying

Say I have two `NSPredicate`s

```
NSPredicate *pa = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^(BOOL)(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [evaluatedObject isKindOfClass:[TestClass class]];
}];

NSPredicate *pb = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^(BOOL)(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [evaluatedObject isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"TestClass")];
}];
```

What I want is that when I put `pa` in a `NSDictionary` and associate it with another object, say `obj`, later when I check in the dictionary using `pb` I get back `obj`.

Is that how it works?

I see that `NSPredicate` implements `NSCopying`, so I'm hoping that it works as a key. But I'm not sure about the case I outlined above.

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730076/using-class-as-key-in-nsdictionary

Comment: @ValentinShamardin Non sequitur, that has nothing to do with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSPredicate` *does override* `isEqual`, but this seems to be useful only in
very simple cases:

```
NSPredicate *pa = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"foo = 'bar'"];
NSPredicate *pb = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"foo = 'bar'"];
BOOL b = [pa isEqual:pb]; // --> YES
```

In this case you could put an object into a dictionary using key `pa` and get the
object back using key `pb`.

But this does not work with block-based predicates at all, even if they reference the
*same block*:

```
BOOL (^block)(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) = ^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [evaluatedObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]];
};
NSPredicate *pa = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:block];
NSPredicate *pb = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:block];
BOOL b = [pa isEqual:pb]; // --> NO
```

And even if that would work, it would require in your case that the two *blocks*
in the predicate are recognized as equal, which is not the case:

```
BOOL (^block1)(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) = ^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [evaluatedObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]];
};
BOOL (^block2)(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) = ^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [evaluatedObject isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"NSString")];
};
BOOL b = [block1 isEqual:block2]; // --> NO
```

Finally it turns out that two *blocks with the same body* are not equal:

```
BOOL (^block1)(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) = ^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [evaluatedObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]];
};
BOOL (^block2)(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) = ^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [evaluatedObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]];
};
BOOL b = [block1 isEqual:block2]; // --> NO
```

So you can use a predicates as a key in a dictionary, but at least for block-based
predicates this is pretty useless.

Comment: Your test is much more comprehensive than mine. Thanks!

Comment: @yulan6248: You are welcome. - It was an interesting problem!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use any object as a key as long as its class implements `NSCopying`.

Comment: But does it actually work as what I expected? It's possible that a class implements `<NSCopying>` but does not override `isEqual:`; if this is true with `NSPredicate` then it would be useless to use it in a dictionary since only the exact same instance would return the value I previously set.

Comment: @yulan6248 It is possible, but it's unlikely. Conceptually, copiability means that there's an unambiguous and easy definition of two objects being equal. In fact, if someone makes their class conform to `NSCopying` but they don't override `isEqual:`, they deserve to be bitch slapped. (But hey, why don't you **try** it?)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it doesn't work as I expected. Although `NSPredicate` implements `NSCopying`, the fact that a predicate can contain an arbitrary block should make it obvious that it would be virtually impossible to compare two `NSPredicate`s reliably.

Tested on my machine, even the same predicate instance used to query the dictionary won't return the previous set value. My guess is that when the dictionary takes the predicate it copies it, and because the implementation of `isEqual:` for `NSPredicate` probably only returns true on equal pointers the original predicate instance compared to the its copy also returns false.